# No matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::ScriptOrigin' || candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable

Tags: c++, v8

I am using invoking a  class inside my project src c++ file as

```
ScriptOrigin script_origin(
        isolate_,
        script_name,
        Integer::New(isolate_, 0),                            // line offset
        Integer::New(isolate_, 0),                            // column offset
        False(isolate_),                                      // isCrossOrigin
        Local<Integer>(),                                     // scriptId
        Local<Value>(),                                       // sourceMapURL
        False(isolate_),                                      // isOpaque
        False(isolate_),                                      // isWASM
        su.IsNoModule() ? False(isolate_) : True(isolate_));
```

Tried hardcoding the Local() as a random integer value also . Still getting the below error

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::ScriptOrigin'
      ScriptOrigin script_origin(
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 10 were provided 
note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 10 were provided
```

Am i invoking the class wrongly? i do not understand the mismatch arguments note

This is the source code of the class inside a v8 include file

```
 class V8_EXPORT ScriptOrigin {
 public:
  V8_INLINE ScriptOrigin(Isolate* isolate, Local<Value> resource_name,
                         int resource_line_offset = 0,
                         int resource_column_offset = 0,
                         bool resource_is_shared_cross_origin = false,
                         int script_id = -1,
                         Local<Value> source_map_url = Local<Value>(),
                         bool resource_is_opaque = false, bool is_wasm = false,
                         bool is_module = false,
                         Local<Data> host_defined_options = Local<Data>())
      : v8_isolate_(isolate),
        resource_name_(resource_name),
        resource_line_offset_(resource_line_offset),
        resource_column_offset_(resource_column_offset),
        options_(resource_is_shared_cross_origin, resource_is_opaque, is_wasm,
                 is_module),
        script_id_(script_id),
        source_map_url_(source_map_url),
        host_defined_options_(host_defined_options) {
    VerifyHostDefinedOptions();
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you perhaps create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Odd that is doesn't show the constructor from the include file you've shown as a candidate. Should be able to work out the mismatched type(s) from the full error message if that constructor is shown.

Comment: I noticed you're using some factory methods to create int and bool types, that looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the parameters you're passing have the wrong type. For example, `Integer::New(isolate_, 0)` produces a `v8::Local<v8::Integer>`, not a C++ `int`. Similarly, `False(isolate_)` produces a `v8::Local<v8::Boolean>`, not a C++ `bool`.

This isn't really related to V8: whenever working with C++, you need to care about the types of your values.

The part where the compiler says ...

```
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not 
viable: requires 1 argument, but 10 were provided 

note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not 
viable: requires 1 argument, but 10 were provided
```

... is just about that it *tried* to match the 10 arguments you supplied with the copy constructor and move constructor (both of which expect 1 argument only), but that failed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but still did not understand the part where the constructor is expecting 1 argument

Comment: @blackpearl I added an explanation to that to the answer